# wireless connection only after power off

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan, wpa-supplicant

I am have strange problems to enable wifi on my box. Basically I have a network minimal install plus `wpa_supplicant` and a wireless usb stick.

Within `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` there is:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

running:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlx00e04c195779 -c <(wpa_passphrase 'XXX' 'XXX')
```

works after a **POWER OFF** (not reboot) and yields:

```
wlx00e04c195779: SME: Trying to authenticate with 78:8a:20:06:9d:e3 (SSID='PAP_MA' freq=2412 MHz)
wlx00e04c195779: Trying to associate with 78:8a:20:06:9d:e3 (SSID='XXX' freq=2412 MHz)
wlx00e04c195779: Associated with 78:8a:20:06:9d:e3
wlx00e04c195779: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlx00e04c195779: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 78:8a:20:06:9d:e3 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlx00e04c195779: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 78:8a:20:06:9d:e3 completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

So that works. **BUT running the same a second time** it yields:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlx00e04c195779: SME: Trying to authenticate with 78:8a:20:06:9d:e3 (SSID='XXX' freq=2412 MHz)
wlx00e04c195779: SME: Trying to authenticate with 78:8a:20:06:99:eb (SSID='XXX' freq=2412 MHz)
.
.
.
```

So it does not authenticate anymore.

`wpa_cli` just yields:

```
 wpa_cli -i wlx00e04c195779
 wpa_cli v2.6
 Copyright (c) 2004-2016, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

 This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
 See README for more details.



 Interactive mode

 Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: wlx00e04c195779 - re-trying
```

I just guess that this might be caused by the wireless stick, since the interface is not »up« after reboot, so do I need to use netplan to active the interface on startup, if so, how?

Am I missing a package here??

Which logs could I scan?

I am really running out of Ideas here and appreciate any kind of help!

[HERE THE OUTPUT OF THE wireless-info script](https://pastebin.com/pqtx28My)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Netplan thinks it is in charge but you haven't any declaration for wireless. Network Manager thought it was in charge until you removed it. Wicd thinks it is in charge but, obviously, isn't.

I suggest that you decide whether wireless or ethernet is your preferred method of connecting and configure that and only that interface.

Assuming, because of the subject of your question, that it is wireless, I suggest that you amend your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx00e04c195779:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Please note that the network name, or SSID, and the password are enclosed in quotes ". Netplan is quite strict about spacing, indentation, etc. Please proofread carefully twice.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot and test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As it turned out, two things were going on here: 1. wicd was not installed properly, 2. the power supply was too weak, so the usb wireless sticks did not work correctly.